# C# How to use the lambda expression tree in linq query syntax

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am new to Lambda expression tree predicates. I am trying to use custom expression tree method in the where condition using the following code. But getting error.

```
from c in context.customers
join d in context.departments on c.deptid equals d.deptid
where (CheckForCriteria(new string{}{....}))

private Expression<Func<Customer,bool>> CheckForCriteria(IEnumerable<string> keywords)
{
    var keywordGroups = keywords.Select(k => k.Split(' ')).ToArray();

    return customer => keywordGroups.
                            All(keywordGroup => keywordGroup.
                                All(keyword => customer.Name.Contains(keyword))));
}
```

Error i am getting is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<...>> to bool'
Cannot convert query expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Can anyone help me to identify what i have done wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure for 100% that I understand what you're doing here. But the "where" statement requires some operator actions to work. So you can try to use "select" instead of "where" here.

**Example:**

```
var result = from c in context.customers
             join d in context.departments on c.deptid equals d.deptid
             select CheckForCriteria(new [] { "..." });
```

**Example (method chain):**

```
var result = context.customers.Join(context.departments, c => c.deptid, d => d.deptid, (c, d) => new { c, d })
                              .Select(x => CheckForCriteria(new [] { "..." }));
```

To get a list of filtered names you can try this:

```
var result = (from c in context.customers
              join d in context.departments on c.deptid equals d.deptid
              select CheckForCriteria(new string[] { "..." })).Name).ToList();
```